# Was Shiva ever incarnated by taking birth from womb?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Krishna and Rama were born to humans by taking birth from womb. What about Shiva?

Comment: No,Shiva cannot take an avatar in women's womb. Only Swami Vivekananda was the one who himself was Lord Shiva. So,this means Shiva had took once only in a woman's womb and that was Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: "No,Shiva cannot take an avatar in women's womb.". Any sources to back this point ?

Comment: Adi Shankara is considered as an incarnation of Lord Shiva. Rishi Durvasa was also an incarnation of Lord Shiva.

Comment: @NithinSridhar Was Durvasa born from womb? Shiva Purana doesn't explicitly mention that he was born from womb.

Comment: Durvasa was son of Atri and Anasuya.

Comment: @NithinSridhar i know the story of Atri and Durvasa. What Goltu said seems to be true. I don't find any scriptures where Shiva was born from womb.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Shouldn't birth be from the womb by default- like unless Durvasa had an unusual birth isn't it understood that he was born from Anasuya?

Comment: @Goltu What is the scriptural evidence for Swami Vivekananda being an avatara of Shiva?

Comment: Hanuman is incarnation of Lord shiva , he was born from womb !!! You are just asking question by your own speculation, read scriptures. Lord Rama and Krishna is incarnation of Lord Srimannarayan who is eternal and beyond birth and death. If any god wants to take birth on earth he have to take birth from woman's womb whether he is Lord Shiva , Brahma or Lord Vishnu.

Comment: And in Vaishnava sects it is not accepted that Lord Krishna is born from Mother's womb , he directly appeared as four-armed lord Vishnu so that's why lord krishna is accepted as Full incarnation of Lord narayan. Lord Krishna is eternal and beyond the birth, death and have 6 opulence (which qualified him supreme god) in Srimad Bhagvadam and also in bhagvad gita he is referred as Swyam Bhagwan  (The Supreme God). So it is useless to argue whether he is born from Mother's womb!

Comment: Ashwathama is an incarnate of Rudra just like Hanuman.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, according to Shiva Mahapurana, Satarudra Samhita Lord Hanumana and Sage Durvasa are the incarnation of Lord Shiva and they have taken birth from the womb of Anjana and Anusuya respectively.

[Lord Hanumana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-99/topic-1) birth is described as:

> तद्वीर्यं स्थापयामासुः पत्रे सप्तर्षयश्च ते।
> प्रेरिता मनसा तेन रामकार्यार्थमादरात्॥ ५॥

> तैर्गौतमसुतायां तद्वीर्यं शम्भोर्महर्षिभिः।
> कर्णद्वारा तथाञ्जन्यां रामकार्यार्थमाहितम्॥ ६॥

> Like a person suffering from lust, Siva at
> the instance, the saptarsis, (the Swan sages) carried the semen of Siva, for the purpose of Šrī Rāma, with respect, **over the tree leaf and inserted the same in the ear of Anjani the daughter of Gautama, through ear to her Womb**.

And [Sage Durvasa](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-98/topic-1) birth is described as:

> अथ ब्रह्मा हरिः शम्भुरवतेरुः स्त्रियां ततः। पुत्ररूपैः प्रसन्नास्ते नानालीलाप्रकाशकाः॥ २४॥

> **Thereafter Brahma, Visnu and Siva, were born as sons from the womb of Anusuya**, who were delightful at heart and performed several Sports.

> विधेरंशाद्विधुर्जज्ञेऽनसूयायां मुनीश्वरात्। आविर्बभूवोदधितः क्षिप्तो देवैः स एव हि।। २५॥

> Moon was born of the womb of Anusuya from the amsa of Brahma, but since the gods threw him in the ocean, he emerged out of the same (at the time of the churning of the ocean).

> विष्णोरंशात्स्त्रियां तस्यामत्रेर्दत्तो व्यजायत। संन्यासपद्धतिर्येन वद्धिता परमा मुने!॥२६॥

> From the aniisa of Visnu, Datta was born
> from the Womb of Anusuya. O Sage, he propagated the best method of Sannyasa.

> दुर्वासा मुनिशार्दूलः शिवांशान्मुनिसत्तमः। जज्ञे तस्यां स्त्रियामत्रेर्वरधर्मप्रवर्तकः॥ २७॥

> O Excellent sage, from the ansa of Šiva,
> Durvasa, the propounder of dharma and the best of the sages was born.

Comment: Why the down vote? Please mention the reason.